# Settings pages not responding in Safari 13.0.4

Tags: lightning

After installing MacOS Catalina 10.15.2 on 12/14/19 I have found that settings pages such as Users, Profiles, etc are unresponsive and appear not to fully load in Lightning Experience. Switching to Classic cures the problem. My Safari version is Version 13.0.4 (15608.4.9.1.3). I don't know if that was upgraded along with MacOS or if it is the same version I was running before the upgrade. Is anybody else experiencing this, and does anybody have another solution for it?

Comment: I'm also seeing this problem. Clearing settings as described in https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204098 does not work.